# Is there a way to check your level stats online?

Tags: super-mario-maker

I've been spending a decent amount of time creating levels in Super Mario Maker. I was curious if there is any way to check your level's stats online or if it can only be checked in-game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the answer is now yes, you can: https://supermariomakerbookmark.nintendo.net/profile/ben_Watson92

Answer (score 6):

I received a response from Nintendo of America support regarding my inquiry about alternate ways to access level stats. They said that, currently, the only way to view your Super Mario Maker Level Stats is in game. They did note that they would take my suggestion of a separate online viewing tool and pass it along to the proper departments and that that could eventually lead to implementation of a different way to view level stats online.

Comment: If nothing else, you can check the comments online (every stage uploaded is posted to Miiverse).

Answer (score 4):

Currently the answer is no, you are unable to check your stats online. I've dug up [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MarioMaker/comments/3kx5ld/is_there_any_way_to_view_your_level_stats_online/) from Reddit. Not sure if you would count Reddit as a credible source, but by the looks of it it cannot be done.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau There's nothing to say. Basically, all the thread says is "no".

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Better?